# How to open a Photo lightbox programmatically Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I've got this Photo lightbox containing some info, and I'd like to open it programmatically using `$('#popupDetails').popup('open');`, it works with other types of popup, but it fails to work with lightboxes. What am I doing wrong?.

Any advice is appreciated.

What have I tried:

- Initializing it before executing:

  > `$('#popupDetails').popup();`
  >   `$('#popupDetails').popup('open');`
- Emulating a click on the `<a href="#popupDetails" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="fade"><img class="popphoto" alt="Details"></a>`, but it's not professional.

**My Code**:

```js
$('#popupDetails').popup();
$('#popupDetails').popup('open');
```

```css
.detail {
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #72a9dc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0" />

<a href="#popupDetails" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="fade">
  <img class="popphoto" alt="Details">
</a>

<div data-role="popup" id="popupDetails" data-overlay-theme="b" data-theme="b" data-corners="false" style="margin-top:20px">
  <a href="#" data-rel="back" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-a ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-right"></a>
  <div style="text-align:center;" alt="Item Details">
    <span class="detail">Code:</span>
    <p>123</p>
    <span class="detail">User:</span>
    <p>John T. Dock</p>
    <span class="detail">Title:</span>
    <p>A Huge Task</p>
    <span class="detail">Description:</span>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <span class="detail">Module:</span>
    <p>Accounting</p>
    <span class="detail">Customer:</span>
    <p>John F. Duck</p>
    <span class="detail">Date:</span>
    <p>12/12/2015</p>
    <span class="detail">Priority:</span>
    <p>High</p>
    <span class="detail">Sorting:</span>
    <p>99</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Here it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/1x0qxpcn/3/ perhaps you need a higher version of jQuery

Comment: @BasvanStein That's great, I'm gonna try different versions to see which suits my case, thanks

Comment: I don't know why, but it fails when I try it on my server or anywhere else but on JSfiddle, even though I'm using the 2.4.1 and the mobile 1.4.1 JS and CSS just like on JSfiddle

Comment: Do you execute the javascript onDocument ready? Because that is the only difference that I can think of jsFiddle uses and you might not.

Comment: Never mind, I'm stupid, thanks and sorry @BasvanStein

Comment: I don't think you are stupid, most problems have a very simple but easily overlooked solution. Glad it works, I will post the solution as the answer so it can be accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to execute your javascript in the Document ready event.

```
// popup ready to fire
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#popupDetails').popup('open');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer dude, I was focusing on the wrong thing +1